# Read in and execute multiline SQL text file into Python program

Tags: python, list, text, split

I have a create_table.txt file that looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE TABLE_A;
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
ID VARCHAR(100),
NAME VARCHAR(100),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
);
ALTER TABLE TABLE_A ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE_A(ID);
...
```

I want to read in that file into a list, separated by semi-colon, to then be iterated over and executed.  If these all existed on one line I could just do a line.split() but the new lines are throwing me off.

If it would be easier to change it to a .sql file I could do that too.

I have tried:

```
list1 = []
with open('create_table.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line.split(';')
        list1.append(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach uses `re.findall` with dot all mode enabled:

```py
inp = '''DROP TABLE TABLE_A;
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
ID VARCHAR(100),
NAME VARCHAR(100),
ADDRESS VARCHAR(100)
);
ALTER TABLE TABLE_A ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE_A(ID);'''

sql = re.findall(r'(.*?;)\s*', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(sql)
```

This prints:

```
['DROP TABLE TABLE_A;',
 'CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (\nID VARCHAR(100),\nNAME VARCHAR(100),\nADDRESS VARCHAR(100)\n);',
 'ALTER TABLE TABLE_A ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TABLE_A(ID);']
```